# Automatically update value in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say we got two tables that are called A and B.

A table has a number type column called 'warned' and B table has a string type column called 'active'.

When warned column's value is changed as 5, I want to automatically update active column's value.

Comment: Looks like you need to read about procedures, triggers, materialized views and query change notifications. And only then to choose a preferred approach. I would suggest to use procedural approach with single point of data change, ie create a set of pl/sql procedure for data manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use after update trigger
something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER b_update 
AFTER UPDATE
ON A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.warned = 5 THEN 
   UPDATE B SET ACTIVE = 'YOUR VALUE';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: It helps me a lot! :)

Comment: use where clause with update statement to update the correct row sin B table. Use appropriate exception handling as well. I assume you want it to be updated automatically that's why I am suggesting trigger. Otherwise, you can go for a more preferable approach as mentioned by @Sayan.